# Spring JPA @Any

Tags: hibernate, database-design, relational-database, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have one Announce class with following relation;

```
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "recipient_type"))
@AnyMetaDef(
        idType = "long", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = SchoolClass.class, value = "SC"),
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = Student.class, value = "S")
        }
)
@JoinColumn(name = "recipient_id")
@JsonIgnore
public Interface recipient;
```

For finding Announces from given recipient, I have following resource;

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM announce WHERE recipient_id = ?1 AND recipient_type = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<Announce> findByRecipient(long id, String type);
```

Is there better way to do this ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: and where is this @Any coming from? It's not JPA

Comment: Any coming from hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You can @Query Announce with the recipient's interface (which you named Interface):

```
@Query("select a from Announce a where a.recipient = :recipient")
Announce findByRecipient(Interface recipient);
```

Then you can call findByInterface using the entities that implements Interface to receive an Announce object.